# Can't start MySql service in Windows 7

Tags: mysql

Hi Iam trying to start mysqld on windows 7. I have installed mysql 5.5.15.
I cant start mysqld as a service. I had MS SQL service running before MySql, stopped that service before starting mysql as service.

Comment: Look in the error logs what the problem is

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed MySQL on the machine before? If so, you need to make sure you stop that service and uninstall it completely before you try to reinstall MySQL.

If not.. try reinstalling and following these [directions](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-mysql-windows-7.php) carefully.

Comment: how to uninstall it completely? I have uninstall then remove the folders and even remove the service. then restart and try to install again. but it does not work. can you give us some advices?